# Right triangles geometry problem

Tags: geometry

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be a right triangle with $C=90°$ and $BC$ greater than $AC$. Let $G$ be its centroid. Let $E$ be a point in the line $AC$ such that $EG$ is perpendicular to $AB$. Let $F$ be the intersection of $EG$ with $BC$ and $D$ be the intersection of $EG$ with $AB$. Given that $EF=2FG$, find angle $∠ABC$.

I put the point $P$ as the projection of $C$ on the line $ED$. As $G$ is the centroid of $\triangle{ABC}$, $PG=2GD$. Moreover, $∠FCP=∠ABC$. Letting $PF=x$, $EP=2-x$, $PG=1+x$, $CP=x·\cot{∠B}$, $CF=x·\sec{∠B}$, $EP=x·(\cot{∠B})^2$,$EC=x·\cot{∠B}·csc{∠B}$.
Unfortunately, I cannot calculate $x$, so I cannot solve this system of equations.

Comment: If in coordinates $A,B,C$ are each ordered pairs, then is the "barycenter" $G=(A+B+C)/3$?

Comment: Yes, I've already changed it to centroid. In Portuguese we call it barycenter

Comment: Is it possible to have $EF=2FG$? My [construction](https://ggbm.at/S9XwVdVD) shows that $EF$ is part of $FG$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add that BC should be greater than AC.

Comment: In this way, B in your sketch should be A, E should be F, and F should be E. So it is possible to have EF=2FG.

Comment: I've done this construction and got the angle equal to 30°. But this question is expected to be done without the aid of Geogebra, just with the aid of trigonometry and plane geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Trigonometric solution:** Let $x$ be the measure of $\angle ABC$.

[image: Trangle ABC]
Then in the triangle $\Delta GCE$ the angle in $E$ is also $x$, complement to $\angle EAD=\angle CAB$, and the angle in $C$ has measure $90^\circ +x$, since $\Delta CC'B$ is isosceles. So the angle $\angle CGE$ measures $90^\circ-2x$. Now we look closer to the proportions $CF:FG$ and $CF:FE$ in the corresponding two triangles, and immediately get a relation determining $x$:
$$
2
=\frac{EF}{FG}
=\frac{EF}{CF}
 \cdot
 \frac{CF}{FG}
=\frac 1{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\sin(90^\circ-2x)}{\sin x}
=\frac {\cos(2x)}{\sin^2 x}\ .
$$
We get
$$
\cos(2x)=2\sin^2 x=1-\cos(2x)\ ,
$$
so $\cos(2x)=1/$, so $2x=60^\circ$, so $x=30^\circ$.

**Synthetic solution:**

Let $S$ be the mid point of the segment $EF$.

Let $T$ be the mid point of the segment $CG$.

[image: Triangle $ABC$ with constructed points $S,T$.]

By construction, because of $ES=SF=FG$, and $CT=TG$, the segment $TF$ is half of and parallel to $CS$. In particular, the exterior angle $2x$ in $S$ of the isosceles triangle $\Delta CSE$ is parallely moved to the angle $\angle TFG$ in the triangle $\Delta TFG$. In this last triangle we then know two angles, the one in $F$, $2x$, the one in $G$, its complement (as seen inside $\Delta GCE$), so the remained angle in $T$ is a **right angle**. So $CFG$ is an isosceles triangle with equal angles in $C$, and $G$, there equal measures are $x$, and $90^\circ-2x$, so
$$
x =30^\circ\ .
$$
$\square$